# How to convert string into fixed number of bytes?

Tags: string, python-2.7, byte

I want to create an 8 bytes sized variable that will include my string.

```py
byte = 8_bytes_variable
str = 'hello'
# Put str inside byte while byte still remains of size 8 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string first by adding some space to the beginning of it. Here I assumed that each character takes 1 bit. (Chinese characters take more)

```
str = 'hello'
if len(str.encode('utf-8')) > 8:
    print("This is not possible!")
else:
    str2 = '{0: >8}'.format(str)    # adds needed space to the beginnig of str
    byte = str2.encode('utf-8')
```

In order to get the original string later, you can use `lstrip()`:

```
str2 = byte.decode()
str = str2.lstrip()
```